# Why can't I put a rospy.Timer in a while loop?

Tags: ros, python

I am trying to be able to control when do I publish so I tried to put the rospy.Timer in a while loop. I did not use rospy.Rate or rate.sleep because I found out that it somehow interferes with the signal of another node(if someone could help on this would be nice too).
However when I put the rospy.Timer in a loop it does not seem working as intended

This is my publisher code

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python

     import rospy
     from std_msgs.msg import Int16
     from std_msgs.msg import String

     pub_1=rospy.Publisher('file_update',Int16,queue_size=30)
     shutdown_signal = False  # Flag to indicate whether to shut down the publisher
     rate=10
     def update_file():

     global shutdown_signal
     while not shutdown_signal:
         rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1/rate),publish)

  def publish(event):

     num_msg=23
     pub_1.publish(num_msg)

  def shutdown(data):

     global shutdown_signal
     shutdown_signal = True
     #rospy.loginfo("Received shutdown signal")

 if __name__ == '__main__':

    rospy.init_node('file_update_publisher', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('shutdown_publisher', String, shutdown)
    try:
        update_file()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        print("An exception occured")
```

And this is my subscriber code

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3

  import rospy
  from std_msgs.msg import String
  from std_msgs.msg import Int16

  def file_update_callback(data):

      number=data.data
      print(number)
      shutdown_pub = rospy.Publisher('shutdown_publisher', String, queue_size=1)
      shutdown_pub.publish("Shutdown")

  def listen_file_update():
      rospy.init_node('file_update_listener', anonymous=True)
      rospy.Subscriber('file_update', Int16, file_update_callback)
      rospy.spin()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
     listen_file_update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rospy.Timer` object is designed to operate asynchronously. When you create a Timer inside a while loop, it attempts to create a new timer on each iteration of the loop. This will lead to unexpected behavior, as these timers are not being properly managed or canceled.

The callback `publish` in the Timer is designed to be called at regular intervals specified by the duration.

Revised publisher code (with minimal changes):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int16, String

pub_1 = rospy.Publisher('file_update', Int16, queue_size=30)
shutdown_signal = False

def publish(event):
    if not shutdown_signal:
        num_msg = 23
        pub_1.publish(num_msg)

def shutdown(data):
    global shutdown_signal
    shutdown_signal = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rate = 10
    rospy.init_node('file_update_publisher', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('shutdown_publisher', String, shutdown)
    timer = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1/rate), publish)
    rospy.spin()
    timer.shutdown()
```

Feel free to build on this code, specifically the `update_file` function. If you are starting ROS development, I would recommend switching to [ROS 2](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/).